# ImportError: No module named awscli.clidriver because of wrong path for python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-sdk

I had installed Python and AWSCLI on Windows 10 and it was working fine a while ago. Now when I run `aws ssm start-session` commands I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named awscli.clidriver
```

I know this is because Python cannot find the cli driver and is usually because it is not installed [properly]. In my case it was working fine and I think another installation that included Python broke it. I think it could have been Anaconda. I have done installed it again using `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user` and still get the same error. So my guess is that it is happening because I have two versions of python installed and somehow the right one is not found or part of my path. How can I investigate and resolve this issue?

Comment: You could try creating a virtualenv and trying with that. Or check the sys-packages list in each installation and find which one is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which version of python your default is set too. You can change the preference default if you need to use a newer version of python. 
You can check your version via your cli:

```
python --version
```

To set a user preference you can use `alias`

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.4' # or whatever your path name is.
```

Once you have done that re-login or source your `-bash.rc` file with

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Then check your python version again to confirm it worked.